# Scrolling speed of images on Gallery view

Tags: android, coverflow

I am creating a [cover flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_Flow) of images by extending the `Gallery` class.

The gallery view is being displayed properly but the speed with which the images scroll from right to left, and vice-versa, is very fast.

Is there any way we can **regulate speed of the movement of the images** on the horizontal direction from right to left, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the animation duration of the `Gallery` object. Using the API `setAnimationDuration`.

Increasing the duration of the animation should give you a slower speed while scrolling through the images.

I am not aware of the default animation duration so you might have to figure it out via trial and error method. :) (If you do experiment on this, can you post your findings here?)